# "Comments are not Supported in JSON because developers used to pass instructions to the parser". Can anyone explain what this means?

Tags: json, comments

I was searching for the reason behind removing Comments in JSON although many parsers have the capability of reading comments. The reason sited by Douglas Crawford, is because of the practice of passing instructions to the parsers via comments. Can anyone explain what that means?

Answer (score 0):

this brings trouble, data is data, consistency should not brought uncertainty, says you could read environment variable or control layout / rules or so? i guess